# In Spring, how do I bind a list of integers to a RequestParam?

Tags: spring, http-request-parameters

I have parameters from the client that are being sent such as

```
ids[] = 11
ids[] = 12
ids[] = 21
```

On the server side, I have a Spring controller with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping("/delete.x")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> delete(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("ids[]") List<Integer> ids) {
```

When I try to iterate over the collection of ids as follows:

```
for (Integer id : ids) {
```

I get an exception as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Is Spring changing the type of ids to List<String>? No matter I suppose, how can I avoid this issue and have the ids stored as Integers inside of a List?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that java has type erasure. So at runtime a `List<Integer>` is equivalent than a `List<String>` and spring has no way of knowing you want Integers into your list.

A work around might be using a integer array instead of a List of integers.

```
@RequestMapping("/delete.x")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> delete(HttpServletRequest request,
  @RequestParam("ids[]") Integer[] ids) {
```

Answer (score 1):

For string I have done like this and this running properly

```
<form action="addArticals">
    <input name="artical[]" type="text"> </input>
    <input name="artical[]" type="text"> </input>
    <input name="artical[]" type="text"> </input>
    <input name="artical[]" type="text"> </input>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <input name="artical[]" type="text"> </input>
</form>
```

and in controller it will be like this

```
@RequestMapping("/addArticals")
public String articalStore(@RequestParam("artical[]")List<String> articals, Modal modal)
{
}
```

Comment: The OP clearly states that he wants Spring to bind to Integer and not String. String is not an issue here.